# How to set up build dependencies of a code generation task?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have 2 msbuild projects A and B in the same Visual Studio 2019 solution. A depends on B.

- B is a tool that can generate code.
- A contains a task to run that code generation and produce a C# file (Stuff.cs) for compilation as a part of A.

My goal is to set up a simple and intuitive incremental build with minimal boilerplate. If B source code is changed or the generated file is not found, that should trigger the code generation task to be re-run, and then rebuild A. (otherwise it should not re-run code generation)

The problem is that this works first time when the code is not generated yet, but on the 2nd change of B it bypasses the code generation step when A gets rebuilt. It simply says that A is "up-to-date".

B is an executable that I run inside the A's csproj with `Exec` like so:

```
  <Target Name="GenerateStuff" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" 
    Inputs="$(SolutionDir)\B\bin\$(Configuration)\B.exe" 
    Outputs="$(ProjectDir)\Stuff.cs">
      <Exec Command="$(SolutionDir)\B\bin\$(Configuration)\B.exe" />
  </Target>
```

Thus for some reason it doesn't respect this "Inputs" as a valid trigger.

I'm also looking for more documentation and examples related to this.

Comment: Are you sure that `B.exe` has a newer modification date? Does the project reference the B csproj? Does the incremental build work when building with msbuild.exe or is the up-to-date message from VS? (VS has a heuristic up-to-date check that avoids calling MSBuild at all)

Comment: A has B in the list of build dependencies (not references), so when I build A, the B project gets built, and B.exe is updated, but A stays "up-to-date" (according to a message from VS), and the task is not re-run.

Comment: But does it build correctly using msbuild from the command line (developer command prompt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `B.exe` as an input to the project system so that the Visual Studio up-to-date check calls MSBuild when `B.exe` changes - this is an additional heuristic that VS runs before even calling MSBuild.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="$(SolutionDir)\B\bin\$(Configuration)\B.exe" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. One problem is that B.exe now appears in Solution Explorer as an "ignored" file. Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Maybe try adding a `Visible="false"`